# ReferenceError: $ is not defined when debug

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-code, referenceerror

I have this error message ReferenceError: $ is not defined when using vscode built-in debugger node.js Here is the html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>14. Getting Started with jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the app.js

```
$(function() {
// start up code goes here
alert("this works!");
});
```

I put a breakpoint at the alert line and run the debug (node.js) in vscode. It stopped at $(function() { - the first line of app.js with error message of ReferenceError: $ is not defined. Seems like jQuery is not loaded.

I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but none of them works. Please help.

Comment: jQuery is actually not loaded, but this is SO basic. I don't know why you talk about node.js, it is a simple HTML page, can't you just open the console and check for errors?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the jQuery loaded in your HTML file in NodeJS, you need to associate it with `$` first:

Go to the script where you want to use it, and write:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery;
```

If that does not work, install the jQuery npm package by opening your terminal inside the folder of your script and then typing:

```
npm i jquery
```

Then write

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
```

in your script.