# ReferenceError: $ is not defined in Vscode editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-code, console, vscode-extensions

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I have tried everything and nothing seems to work!
In fact my code works but I keep getting this error from the output console in VScode editor and not in the google chrome console.

I moved the cnd to the end and the beginning of html file.
I put Cdn library before my script.
I download a local Jquery library, it doesn't work.
Try a ready function and it works but it gives me the same error in Vscode console.

> Blockquote

This is the error:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
       ^
```

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Note:I know that questions about this error have been answered before but no solution has worked for me.

Comment: If `$` is not defined, then JQuery is not loaded when this line is executed. Is your JQuery loaded before your JS code ?

Comment: If `$` is defined at runtime but VScode doesn't know it, and considers it undefined, you can use `define const $;` at the top of your file and VScode will stop complaining.

Comment: Yes is loaded, I can see this alert from my funcion: in chrome when the pages open!

Comment: Hi, can you show me and example of ---- define const $, sorry  I am begginer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer you looking for. I guess you are using nodejs as debugger instead of java-script inside of browser.

[ReferenceError: $ is not defined when debug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48457867/7951586)

Solution:
Run a live local web server with your javascript script embedded with Jquery

Comment: What about `In fact my code works`? :) Wouldn't be the case in NodeJS.

Comment: I am using Node.js v14.4.0., but it shows the same error!

Comment: In fact if it works, the codes run as supposed but I can't remove the error from the output console! :)

Comment: Hi Chak, I follow your advice! but this, ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: Can you reproduce on https://codepen.io/ or other online ide?

Comment: another solution would be using the defer tag
`<script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>`

Comment: when you delete `window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");`. the script should work fine in `codepen`

Comment: I think you have some problem in environment setting in vscode debugger

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer
Install this plugin in vscode, and try to run it.

Comment: I have this plugin install, maybe is this code runner plugin the problem!